# How to extract value from http response under html script tag in JMeter?

Tags: javascript, http, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and I was trying to extract the value, i.e., abc, from the response code during a get request. It is placed under the html code and under script tag within a function. It would be something like this:

```
    <html>
            <head>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            function validate() {
                                    ....
                                    document.getElementById("abc").value = "123";
                                    ....
                            }
                    </script>
            </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: `i.e., abc, from the response code ` ? The response code or the response body ? maybe you are looking for a regexp extractor https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjmeter%5D+extract

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this `abc` using regular expression like:

```
document.getElementById\("(\w+)"\).value = "123";
```

Explanation:

- [Meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) need to be escaped with the backslash
- `\w` - matches any letter or digit or underscore
- `+` - repetition (more than one letter or digit)

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)